# jQuery - how to modify a text input value by changing another element's value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I searched, but couldn't find anything that really corresponds to what I'm trying to do.

So I have a text input and next to it and number input. What I want to do is modify the text input's value when the number input has been changed. But I don't want to replace the value entirely.

This is essentially what I currently have:

```
<input id='field_4' name='4' value='64_to_74_weight_3'/>
<input id='field_4-weight' type='number' min='1' max='5' value='3' data-for='#field_4' />
```

What I'm trying to do is only change the number after **weight_** to correspond to the number being chosen by the number input. I know I can get the last character by using slice(-1), but I can't get it to change it while preserving the rest of the text input's value.

Can anybody help with this? Thank you

Edit:
I had used something similar to below and thought it would've worked, but figured jQuery would be better, but I couldn't get it working on jsFiddle.

```
function updateInput(weight){
    document.getElementById('field_" . $filter->id . "').value.slice(-1) = weight;
}
```

Comment: Show us the code which you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#field_4-weight").on('change', function() {
    var txtField = $("#field_4"),
        txt = txtField.val();
    txtField.val(txt.slice(0, txt.length-1) + $(this).val());
});
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you. I think when I was trying it in jsFiddle, I was over thinking it which tends to happen when you've been staring at the same code for a while. Thank you again, marked as accepted :)